# Correct place for determiner both

Tags: determiners

What is the difference among the following three sentences?

> **Both** Apple and Google must remove the app.
> Apple and Google **both**
>   must remove the app.
>  Apple and Google must **both** remove the
>   app.

To me the third sentence seems a bit strange because it does not satisfy any grammar rule.

Comment: The first and third are normal. The second is grammatical, but not idiomatic.

Comment: Determiner is usually placed before a noun or a pronoun but in the third sentence it is after a modal. Is this a correct construction?

Comment: According to the Cambridge Dictionary, the third sentence is perfectly fine https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all grammatical, but the first sentence definitely sounds the best.  The "both...and..." construction is fairly common in English.